# Android app Crashing on password field for AppAuth Custom tab intent on Chrome browser(94.0.4606.80) only

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, appauth, android-customtabs

After Opening Custom tab intent clicking on password field crashing application.
And it is only crash if chrome browser version is (94.0.4606.80)

I am using latest appauth lib
implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.10.0'

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.android.chrome:layout/0_resource_name_obfuscated: Binary XML file line #6 in com.android.chrome:layout/0_resource_name_obfuscated: Error inflating class org.chromium.chrome.browser.keyboard_accessory.tab_layout_component.KeyboardAccessoryTabLayoutView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1258187

A newer version of Chrome with this issue fixed is reportedly already being rolled out.

Comment: I see google chrome reverted back old version and current prod version is : 94.0.4606.71,  This issue will be there for user who has updated their chrome version.